# Maintaining Session in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have Creatd an Application using Asp .Net MVC4 framework and published it on a server. At the final Part I am trying to implement Session. I aam giving Username and password at the login screen.
If the username and Password matches then I am using

```
Session["uniqueId"]=username
```

and redirecting to next page. Now whenever i am on any page i am checking this variable to find out which user has logged in and if its empty i am redirecting to login screen otherwise i am displaying some message based on that ID.
Its working fine for 1 PC. But when on LAN i am logging in with different ID on different PC then the variable's Value on previous PC IS being replaced with the newly logged in person's ID.
How to solve this problem and maintain unique session for each Login for each User

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Session["yourid"]=username` or just `HttpContext.Session["yourid"]=username`

Comment: Is that not expected behaviour? When you log in as someone else the value is replaced? Can you explain this further?

Comment: each user will have it's own session, which will be unique for that user in the current browser. Session is bound to a user with a cookie, so if you log in with new credentials, you will override old session (on same PC or a browser)

However, if you wish to create a list of all online users, you can use static variables, or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Name"]`

Comment: No that's the thing, if i login with different credential then that behavior is expected. Right now i am logging in simultaneously with different PC and different credential other PC's are getting affected. After Somebody else logs in on PC-2, after Refreshing the page on PC-1 i am seeing profile of person sitting on PC-2, because the session's id is being replaced .

Comment: See Updated Question

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava What is `Session` in your code? Which session provider do you use?

Comment: You should save logged users somewhere - database, file. When user with the same username logs you should check if he is already logged in and use the id from the table.

Comment: Its Simple Asp .Net Session variable @dlght

Comment: You cannot maintain multiple log-ins with the same user and id without saving the values somewhere. Even the different browsers have different session id and would produce different id for your user.

Comment: users are different, ID's are different passwords are different. Only thing which is same is The session variable where i am saving value.